# MongoDB connection instantly closes - Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the mongodb-driver-sync-4.1.0-rc0 dependency and whenever I connect to the database I can use it within the same method but as soon as i store it as a static var and try accessing it from another class it says "state should be: open". My connection instantly closes after establishing a connection.

```
public static void initializeClient(){
        String uri = "mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@userstats.9vs4b.mongodb.net/izzi?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

        try ( MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)) {

            client = mongoClient;
            izzi = client.getDatabase("izzi").getCollection("userStats");

            System.out.println(getOverallLikes());
            System.out.println(getWinnersLastMonth());
            //after this it closes the connection

        }
    }
```

I get this message when it disconnects: [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:14654}] to userstats-shard-00-02.9vs4b.mongodb.net:27017 because the pool has been closed.

Comment: Here is an example code about creating `MongoClient` and using it in a Java application. When a `MongoClient` is created, by default, it is configured with a _connection pool_ of size 100 (this is specific for Java driver). So, a `MongoClient` can be created and used across the application from a Singleton class. See: [Managing Mongodb connections in Java as Object Oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180119/managing-mongodb-connections-in-java-as-object-oriented/60337641#60337641).

Answer (score 2):

Its behaviour is the normal one; This is a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try ( MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)) 
{
       client = mongoClient;
       izzi = client.getDatabase("izzi").getCollection("userStats");
       System.out.println(getOverallLikes());
       System.out.println(getWinnersLastMonth());
       //after this it closes the connection
}
```

From the documentation:

*The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that **each resource is closed at the end of the statement***

Your resource is the `MongoClient` instance, which will be automatically closed after the last operation inside the `try` clause. As you assigned the `mongoClient` value to your `client` variable, once the `try-clause` is finished and the `mongoClient` closed, `client` will reference a closed session.

Comment: hello.

in my case this worked.

i've copied the code blindly from https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/java-mapping-pojos and didn't think about try-with-resource there.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The above observation of connection being closed is as per the intended functionality of the ***'try with resources'*** feature of Java.

The desired requirement of keeping the connection active can be achieved by using a ***regular try ... catch ... finally block*** with **mongoClient.close()** called explicitly for closing the connection.

Moreover, if the requirement is to call the method from a different class, then the code for closing the connection need to be placed in a different method.

**Working code snippets:**

(a) Connect to MongoDB, fetch data and close connection:

```
    public void myMongoDBClient() {
        MongoClient mongoClient;
        String uri = "mongodb-connection-uri";
        try {
             mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)

             // Fetch data from mongodb
             // Other statements


        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // Error handling

        } finally {
           // Close the conection
           mongoClient.close();
        }
    }
```

(b) Call mongodb client from other classes:

```
public class MyMongoDBClient {

    private static MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    private static String uri = "mongodb-connection-uri";

    public static void initializeClient() {
        try {
             mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // Error handling

        } finally {
           // Close the conection
           mongoClient.close();
        }
    }

   public static void fetchData() throws Exception {
       // Code for fetching data
       // Can be called multiple times from external classes
   }

  public static void close() throws Exception {
      // Close connection.
      // Can be called once from an external class
      mongoClient.close();
  }


}
```